# Warning messages in GSP: "unknown tag"

Tags: grails, gsp, taglib, content-assist, ggts

I am having bunch of warning messages for "g:" | "asset:" etc, in my GSP files. Also, the content assist is not working in the editor. But if I manually type the code, the file executes properly while running in server. But it is very tedious to code without the content assist for the grails taglib elements and also warning messages are annoying.

Ex Warning in editor: "Unknown Tag (asset:image)"

My configuration is as below:
1. Grails 2.4.0 
2. GGTS 3.6.2

I have the grails.tld, with all the grails tags mentioned in the tld, in webapp/web-inf/tld folder but seems GGTS is not able to recognize the tld. I read in various similar questions that we do not have to explicitly specify the taglibs at the top of each GSP page.

Need suggestions on what can be done to resolve the warnings and make the content assist work properly in the editor.